# How do I make an object in my scene into an object I can instance using python?

Tags: python, mesh, objects, add-on

I'm in the process of writing an addon that generates buildings based on a group of assets such as bits of wall and roofing.

My current plan is to somehow dynamically save custom assets, including UV coordinate, textures, etc. to an object that I can create using python. (Much in the same way objects are typically created in python, only they would be defined by an object in the scene, rather than pre-defined by another piece of code)

For instance, when I want to create a Monkey with python, (and who wouldn't?) I can just call bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_monkey_add() and viola, I have a monkey. Is there a way to take my active object and dynamically create a function that is able to recreate it?

Feel free to ask further questions on my dilemma, as I feel I may not be explaining it very well!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select you own object and create a [*Group*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Groups_and_Parenting#Grouping_objects)

- Select your object(s)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> to create a group
- After that you can create instances of this group by calling:

  bpy.ops.object.group_instance_add(group='GroupName', view_align=False, location=(0,0,0))